# Matplotlib: Two datasets on one image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two datasets on a single figure. Essentially this is for tracking fluids in a 2 dimensional porespace.

Both data sets are 250x250 `numpy array`, the first with data ranging from 0 to 1, the second with data ranging from 2 to 3. The first one is tracking the amount of fluid in a location so 0 would mean 0% fluid and .35 would mean 35% fluid, etc. Similarly the second array would have 2.00 for 0%, 2.35 for 35%, 3.00 for 100%, etc.

Plotting them individually is pretty easy and you get a nice shade effect according to the % of fluid in a location in the array.

**What I want to do is plot both images on the same figure** with the first data set using Blues (so that 0 is white and 1 is blue and the data in the middle being shaded according to the blue colormap) and then plot the second data set on top of that using Greens (so 2 will be white and 3 will be green, and the data in the middle being shaded according to the green colormap).

Comment: Where is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you post the images you're trying to overlap?

Answer (score 3):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy
x = numpy.arange(10)
y = x
z = -x
pyplot.plot(x, y)
pyplot.plot(x, z)  # pyplot.plot(x, y, x, z) works too.

pyplot.show()
```

You just plot everything before calling show and it'll show up on the same image.

You can also using do the same with imshow, scatter, etc all on the same.